# PHP xml SOAP and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, soap

I have been trying to figure out how to make a soap request using php/laravel. But from all the research on internet since two days now the only things that I can find are old rusty php codes to make soap requests non of them even worked:

Here is a snipped that I am trying to make it work so I have a general view of those soap requests but I only get errors not able to make a soapclient:

```
<?php


$aHTTP['http']['header'] =  "User-Agent: PHP-SOAP/5.5.11\r\n";

$aHTTP['http']['header'].= "username: XXXXXXXXXXX\r\n"."password: XXXXX\r\n";

$context = stream_context_create($aHTTP);

$client=new SoapClient("http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl",array('trace' => 1,"stream_context" => $context));

$result =  $client::__getFunctions();

var_dump($result);
```

since it looks super hard to me to find any info about the soap with php any idea ?

Comment: SOAP is, indeed, a pain in the ass. Does your code work to get a list of functions? Even after having worked with SOAP APIs for a decade or so, I still frequently need to ask vendors for sample code or assistance.

Comment: I have been working with JSON REST pretty well never done soap php before when I try it feels like I am dealing with very old stuff I haven't been able to find any good resource at least how to create an xml file and parse it. php manual its super harsh most of the examples they don't work ! And I don't even understand why a service like this should exists when we have JSON

Comment: It's an older tech - you won't see many *new* SOAP APIs. That said, you should basically never be touching raw XML when using the SOAP classes.  You're going to need docs for this SOAP API.

Comment: What are the errors and does the username and password need to be an HTTP header or a SOAP header?

Answer (score -1):

This is a sample of a soap request I currently make to a payment provider via php using curl statements. Basically map the xml request you want to make in a string. The string will be sent in the curl post fields and the response returned.

```
$soapdata="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:tns='tns:ns'>
<soapenv:Header>
  <tns:CheckOutHeader>
    <MERCHANT_ID>$merchantid</MERCHANT_ID>
    <PASSWORD>$password</PASSWORD>
    <TIMESTAMP>$timestamp</TIMESTAMP>
  </tns:CheckOutHeader>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
  <tns:processCheckOutRequest>
    <MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_ID>$merchanttransactionid</MERCHANT_TRANSACTION_ID>
    <REFERENCE_ID>$referenceid</REFERENCE_ID>
    <AMOUNT>$amount</AMOUNT>
    <MSISDN>$mobileno</MSISDN>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ENC_PARAMS></ENC_PARAMS>
    <CALL_BACK_URL>$callbackurl</CALL_BACK_URL>
    <CALL_BACK_METHOD>$callbackmethod</CALL_BACK_METHOD>
    <TIMESTAMP>$timestamp</TIMESTAMP>
  </tns:processCheckOutRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";
//End Soap data
//We call the server for the first time
//end calling function
function makesoaprequest($url, $soapdata)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml', 'Authorization: Basic'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$soapdata");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    //Begin SSL
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    //End SSL
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    return $response;
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Gah. PHP has built-in SOAP handling. There's no reason to be manually creating XML and cURLing it.

Comment: @ceejayoz I did try and use the php soap class but encountered issues with using custom headers. Also the documentation of the php soap class isn't exactly great. As the user also said, he has tried searching for info on it and hasn't come across much to his help. I posted something that works for me after I myself looked for info on this sometime back. I'm guessing somebody who has improvements to make or a better way to use PHP and the internal soap class would post it as an answer or as a comment. This works for me that's why I posted it.